# Stacking Axes Vertically for ios

Tags: scichart

how to stacking axes vertically for ios,like Android with LayoutManager?

I using multiple charts to stack charts,but it can't show CursorModifier from one chart to other chart.so I only using one chart to show multiple panes.

Answer (score 0):

SciChart iOS v2 does not support stacking of axis vertically as Android does.

However, it is possible to stack multiple charts above each other, and share touch events across the chart.

You can find out more in the tutorial: [SciChart iOS, Synchronizing Multiple Charts](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/ios/v2.x/Tutorial%2009%20-%20Linking%20Multiple%20Charts.html)

**Update: SciChart iOS v3**

With SciChart iOS v3 this feature has now been added. [See the documentation here](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/ios/current/axis-layout---stack-axes-vertically-or-horizontally.html).

> It is possible to make axes to stack up vertically or horizontally with SciChart. It requires customization of the default chart layout process. Please refer to the Central Axis article to learn more about the layout processes and ways to customize them.

[image]

With the updated API you can now vertically stack axis to create ECG style charts with SciChart iOS, just as you can in Android, WPF